# Testing whether means of several gamma distributions are equal?

Tags: anova, generalized-linear-model, t-test, gamma-distribution, tukey-hsd-test

I have conducted measurements on bubble sizes on 20 positions in the same foam, each of the 20 positions following a gamma distribution. From the boxplot the mean values appear very similar... Now I would like to test whether the means of the 20 different gamma distributions are significantly different from one another. Normally I would use a t-test, ANOVA and then Tukey, but there is strong evidence against normality.

Method 1:
Krustal wallis test revealed that the bubbles at the 20 positions are nonidentical populations.
From a pairwise wilcoxon test, one of the positions could be excluded. How to get from this to a Tukey test?

Method 2:
I have been modelling a GLM to the bubble size as response predicted by position (20 levels). The model does not fit very well. From this I tried this

```r
    myfit <- glm(Length ~ Distance, family=Gamma(link="identity"), 
                 data = mydata)
    library(multcomp)
    CC <- glht(model=myfit, linfct=mcp(Distance="Tukey"))
```

Some positions were excluded and another iteration allowed improvement of the GLM model. But I am breaking the rules?

> How to treat my data with respect?

Here is the boxplot of my data:
[image]

Comment: What kind of variable is `Distance`? Numeric? Is there any reason to believe that bubble size is monotonic with distance? If not, try as a factor (with 20 levels). It is not clear what you want. Show us a plot?

Comment: If you have reason to believe they’re gamma-distributed, why not the ANOVA analogue in a gamma GLM with the categories as the predictors (just like ANOVA with Gaussian response variables)?

Comment: @Kjetil: Distance is modelled as factor. I belived that the bubble size is monotonic with distance. I can give the boxplot of my distrbutions.

Comment: @Dave: Yes exactly, but how do I perform an ANOVA is there is no normality?

Comment: Do gamma regression on the categorical variable, and test if the non-intercept parameters are non-zero, just as you would do for linear regression with Gaussian response variables.

Comment: That might work...